# ColdFusion - String Function - Find Data In Between 2 Locations

Tags: string, coldfusion, find, coldfusion-9

I'm trying to sort out some string work.

And I need to pull the String Data in betweeen "Det:" and "Evt:"
So only need the XXXB04 returned.  There is always a space after Det: and a space before Evt:.

```
<cfset string = "Add: This Bit Of Data Det: XXXB04 Evt: F2016999999"> 
<cfset rpos = findNoCase("Evt:", string)>
<cfset rpiece = (rpos ? left(string, rpos - 1) : string)>
<br>RPIECE???
<br>
<cfoutput>#rpiece#</cfoutput>
<br><br>
<cfset det = "#Listlast(rpiece,"Det:")#">
<cfset final = "#RTrim(det)#"> 
<cfoutput>#final#</cfoutput>
```

Trying to split it into 2 string checks... With the first stuff - I can get rid of the Evt: stuff - 2nd function doesn't get me exactly whats to the right of Det:

Comment: You could "sort of" cheat with list functions, by using both ":" and a space as delimiters: `getToken(trim(getToken( string, 3, ":")), 1, " ")`. However, the [regex approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36749813/104223) is a lot cleaner IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should work for your example:

```
<cfset string = "Add: This Bit Of Data Det: XXXB04 Evt: F2016999999"> 

<cfset startpos = findNoCase("Det:", string)>
<cfset startpos = startpos + 4>
<cfset endpos = findNoCase("Evt:", string)>
<cfset data = mid(string,startpos,endpos-startpos)>

<cfoutput>
    start: #startpos#<br>
    end: #endpos#<br>
    data: [#data#]<br>
    trimmed data: [#trim(data)#]<br>
</cfoutput>
```

You can run it here: http://trycf.com/gist/865418cb4964ee375619eb316398bd76/acf?theme=monokai

Code explained:
`<cfset startpos = findNoCase("Det:", string)>` will point to the beginning of "Det:"in your string.

```
Add: This Bit Of Data Det: XXXB04 Evt: F2016999999
                      ^
```

`<cfset startpos = startpos + 4>` I am adding four to startpos to move the position past the "Det:" in the string.

```
Add: This Bit Of Data Det: XXXB04 Evt: F2016999999
                          ^
```

`<cfset endpos = findNoCase("Evt:", string)>` will point to the beginning of "Evt:" in your string.

```
Add: This Bit Of Data Det: XXXB04 Evt: F2016999999
                                  ^
```

Now with our pointers set we just get the characters between those two points.
`<cfset data = mid(string,startpos,endpos-startpos)>`

```
Add: This Bit Of Data Det: XXXB04 Evt: F2016999999
                          ^^^^^^^^
```

Notice that the spaces before and after are also included. Those can be removed by calling the trim() function like so `#trim(data)#`.

Comment: Seems to work fine - leaves the Det: in there - but that is workable.  Thx much.

Comment: It shouldn't leave the 'Det:' in there with the addition of the four character positions. Anyway, glad it helped you out.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Regular Expressions and capture groups to grab the part of the string you want. For example:

```
<cfscript>
string = "Add: This Bit Of Data Det: XXXB04 Evt: F2016999999";

det = reReplaceNoCase(string, ".+ Det: ([^ ]+) .+", "\1");
</cfscript>

<cfoutput>
det: [#det#]
</cfoutput>
```

That will output:

> det: [XXXB04]

If you want to know how it works, then the regular expression `.+ Det: ([^ ]+) .+` is matching `_anything_ Det:` (`.` is any character, `+` means one or more) followed by anything that isn't a space `[^ ]+`. The `()` are a capture group which you then refer to as `\1`.